# Is it possible to use a self signed cert with a EC2 instance that requires a client cert from API Gateway

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, ssl, nginx, aws-api-gateway

Here's my situation:

I'm using Elastic Beanstalk to spin up a single EC2 instance without an ELB. I want to have the instance only accessible through the API Gateway. So, I went the route of using client-side certificates for authentication, like what's described [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/getting-started-client-side-ssl-authentication.html).

My EC2 instance has Nginx serving a Rails application. I generated a self-signed certificate on my machine and configured Nginx to use that to serve stuff over https.

Everything seems fine, but when I try to invoke my proxy endpoint from the API Gateway console, I get a 500 error like below:

```
...
Thu Sep 14 02:27:05 UTC 2017 : Endpoint request URI: https://xxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxx.us-east-1.elasticbeanstalk.com/health
Thu Sep 14 02:27:05 UTC 2017 : Endpoint request headers: {x-amzn-apigateway-api-id=xxxxxxxxx, User-Agent=AmazonAPIGateway_xxxxxxxx, Accept-Encoding=identity}
Thu Sep 14 02:27:05 UTC 2017 : Endpoint request body after transformations: 
Thu Sep 14 02:27:05 UTC 2017 : Sending request to https://xxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxx.us-east-1.elasticbeanstalk.com/health
Thu Sep 14 02:27:05 UTC 2017 : Execution failed due to configuration error: General SSLEngine problem
Thu Sep 14 02:27:05 UTC 2017 : Method completed with status: 500
```

I'm thinking that it has something to do with the fact that I'm using a self-signed certificate on the backend. But do I really have to purchase a legitimate certificate in order to complete my setup? Are there any other solutions that would allow me to only accept requests to my EC2 instance only through the API Gateway?

I looked at the Lambda method that is described [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/using-api-gateway-with-vpc-endpoints-via-aws-lambda/), but I didn't want to add any more complexity or latency to the requests.

Here's my Nginx configuration for completeness:

```
server {
      listen       443;
      server_name  localhost;          

      ssl                  on;
      ssl_certificate      /etc/pki/tls/certs/server.crt;
      ssl_certificate_key  /etc/pki/tls/certs/server.key;

      ssl_session_timeout  5m;

      ssl_protocols  TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
      ssl_ciphers "EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH";
      ssl_prefer_server_ciphers   on;
      ssl_client_certificate /etc/pki/tls/certs/api_gateway.cer;
      ssl_verify_client on;

      if ($ssl_protocol = "") {
        return 444;
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see my answer here [AWS API Gateway - Use Client-Side SSL Certificates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46086274/aws-api-gateway-use-client-side-ssl-certificates/46186522#46186522). Sot sure what incompatibility is with NGINX - i managed to create PoC and validate Authenticate with Client-SSL behavior

Comment: Ok, I'll give this a go and see if it works. Didn't go through the certbot steps. That means I have to first get a CNAME record that points to my EB environment's domain? Or can I use the dynamic one that AWS provides and place that as the server_name in my nginx configuration? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It appears at the time of this writing that API Gateway has a [known incompatibility with NGINX around Client Certificates](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-known-issues.html).

Comment: Man that really sucks, especially since half of their supported platforms for elastic beanstalk uses Nginx as it's proxy server. Do you have any suggestions outside of just moving platforms or building my own?